# Iterate with tokenize

Tags: xslt, foreach

I have a document with a 800 letters to and from william, simplified like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <TEI xml:id="1">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="anna"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
    <TEI xml:id="2">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="anna"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
    <TEI xml:id="3">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="bertram"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
    <TEI xml:id="4">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="charlotte"/>
                <persName key="anna"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
    <TEI xml:id="5">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="william"/>
                <persName key="charlotte"/>
                <persName key="bertram"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="anna"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
    <TEI xml:id="6">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="abraham"/>
                <persName key="anna"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
    <TEI xml:id="7">
     <correspDesc>
        <correspAction type="sent">
            <persName key="abraham"/>
            <persName key="william"/>
        </correspAction>
        <correspAction type="received">
            <persName key="charlotte"/>
        </correspAction>
       </correspDesc>
    </TEI>
</root>
```

I want to extract separate correspondences (anna and her secretary abraham belong together, bertram, charlotte).

The output should:
1) write the name of the main correspondence-writer in the TEI-element (that is @correspondence="anna" even though the letter is from abraham)

2) copy all letters by correspondence, i. e. all from anna and abraham, afterwards bertram, afterwards charlotte

3) when (like in letter 5) william and charlotte write together to anna this letter belongs only in annas correspondence but not in charlottes

So far I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:param name="persons">anna-abraham bertram charlotte</xsl:param> <!-- A dash marks correspondences belonging together -->

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:variable name="ruth" select="." as="node()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($persons,' ')">
                <xsl:variable name="correspondents" select="." as="xs:string"/>
                <xsl:variable name="corr-main" select="tokenize($correspondents, '-')[1]" as="xs:string"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($correspondents, '-')">
                <xsl:variable name="correspondent" as="xs:string" select="."/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$ruth/TEI[correspDesc[correspAction[@type='received']/persName/@key = 'william' and not(correspAction[@type='received']/persName/@key = $corr-main) and correspAction[@type='sent']/persName/@key = $correspondent]]|
                    $ruth/TEI[correspDesc[correspAction[@type='sent']/persName/@key = 'william' and not(correspAction[@type='sent']/persName/@key = $corr-main) and correspAction[@type='received']/persName/@key = $correspondent]]">
                    <TEI correspondence="{$corr-main}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                    </TEI>
                </xsl:for-each>   
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity template : copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->  
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which has this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><TEI correspondence="anna" xml:id="1">


<correspDesc>
        <correspAction type="sent">
            <persName key="william"/>
        </correspAction>
        <correspAction type="received">
            <persName key="anna"/>
        </correspAction>
    </correspDesc>
    <text/>
</TEI><TEI correspondence="anna" xml:id="2">
    <correspDesc>
        <correspAction type="sent">
            <persName key="anna"/>
        </correspAction>
        <correspAction type="received">
            <persName key="william"/>
        </correspAction>
    </correspDesc>
    <text/>
</TEI><TEI correspondence="anna" xml:id="4">
    <correspDesc>
        <correspAction type="sent">
            <persName key="charlotte"/>
            <persName key="anna"/>
        </correspAction>
        <correspAction type="received">
            <persName key="william"/>
        </correspAction>
    </correspDesc>
    <text/>
</TEI><TEI correspondence="anna" xml:id="5">
    <correspDesc>
        <correspAction type="sent">
            <persName key="william"/>
            <persName key="charlotte"/>
            <persName key="bertram"/>
        </correspAction>
        <correspAction type="received">
            <persName key="anna"/>
        </correspAction>
    </correspDesc>
    <text/>
</TEI><TEI correspondence="anna" xml:id="6">
    <correspDesc>
        <correspAction type="sent">
            <persName key="abraham"/>
            <persName key="anna"/>
        </correspAction>
        <correspAction type="received">
            <persName key="william"/>
        </correspAction>
    </correspDesc>
    <text/>
</TEI><TEI correspondence="anna" xml:id="6">
    <correspDesc>
        <correspAction type="sent">
            <persName key="abraham"/>
            <persName key="anna"/>
        </correspAction>
        <correspAction type="received">
            <persName key="william"/>
        </correspAction>
    </correspDesc>
    <text/>
</TEI><TEI correspondence="bertram" xml:id="3">
    <correspDesc>
        <correspAction type="sent">
            <persName key="william"/>
        </correspAction>
        <correspAction type="received">
            <persName key="bertram"/>
        </correspAction>
    </correspDesc>
    <text/>
</TEI><TEI correspondence="charlotte" xml:id="4">
    <correspDesc>
        <correspAction type="sent">
            <persName key="charlotte"/>
            <persName key="anna"/>
        </correspAction>
        <correspAction type="received">
            <persName key="william"/>
        </correspAction>
    </correspDesc>
    <text/>
</TEI></root>
```

The output is wrong because it duplicates the letter 6 (both belong to correspondence="anna") and does not output letter 7 though it is written by william to charlotte. Any idea? Any simplification possible?

Comment: I am struggling to understand the relationships between the `TEI` elements, not even the input structure seems consistent, the last `TEI xml:id="7"` has no `correspDesc` which all the others have, obviously all your paths using `correspDesc` will fail for that element. I am also not sure what is supposed to happen with `TEI xml:id="4"` where both `anna` and `charlotte` are senders you want to distinguish, do you want to list that element then twice in the output, with difference `correspondence` attributes?

Comment: I've added the correspDesc to the missing TEI xml:id="7". And yes, I would want that twice as that letter belongs to anna and william as well as charlotte and william

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifp2/7 I have tried to store your correspondence groups into an XPath 3.1 `array(xs:string*)` e.g. `[('anna', 'abraham'), 'bertram', 'charlotte']` represents that you want to process three correspondence groups, the first having two names `anna` and `abraham`, the second and third only having one name (i.e. `bertram` and `charlotte`).

For the search I have used keys to select senders (`<xsl:key name="sent-by" match="TEI" use="correspDesc/correspAction[@type = 'sent']/persName/@key"/>`) and receivers (`<xsl:key name="received-by" match="TEI" use="correspDesc/correspAction[@type = 'received']/persName/@key"/>`) and then I think you can intersect each keyed group with the opposite keyed group on `william` (i.e. intersect sent by e.g. "bertram" with received by "william"):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="persons" as="array(xs:string*)"
     select="[('anna', 'abraham'), 'bertram', 'charlotte']"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="sent-by" match="TEI" use="correspDesc/correspAction[@type = 'sent']/persName/@key"/>
  <xsl:key name="received-by" match="TEI" use="correspDesc/correspAction[@type = 'received']/persName/@key"/>

  <xsl:variable name="sent-by-william" select="key('sent-by', 'william')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="received-by-william" select="key('received-by', 'william')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:variable name="root" select="."/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each select="1 to array:size($persons)">
              <xsl:apply-templates 
                 select="key('sent-by', $persons(.), $root) intersect $received-by-william | 
                         key('received-by', $persons(.), $root) intersect $sent-by-william">
                  <xsl:with-param name="correspondence" select="$persons(.)[1]"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TEI">
      <xsl:param name="correspondence"/>
      <TEI correspondence="{$correspondence}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </TEI>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That gives the result (once I corrected the `xml:id="7"` element to have a `correspDesc` element)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <TEI correspondence="anna" xml:id="1">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="anna"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
   <TEI correspondence="anna" xml:id="2">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="anna"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
   <TEI correspondence="anna" xml:id="4">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="charlotte"/>
                <persName key="anna"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
   <TEI correspondence="anna" xml:id="5">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="william"/>
                <persName key="charlotte"/>
                <persName key="bertram"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="anna"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
   <TEI correspondence="anna" xml:id="6">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="abraham"/>
                <persName key="anna"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
   <TEI correspondence="bertram" xml:id="3">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="bertram"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
   <TEI correspondence="charlotte" xml:id="4">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="charlotte"/>
                <persName key="anna"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
        <text/>
    </TEI>
   <TEI correspondence="charlotte" xml:id="7">
        <correspDesc>
            <correspAction type="sent">
                <persName key="abraham"/>
                <persName key="william"/>
            </correspAction>
            <correspAction type="received">
                <persName key="charlotte"/>
            </correspAction>
        </correspDesc>
    </TEI>
</root>
```

Not sure whether you can use XSLT 3 (available since Saxon 9.8) but it is of course easy to build some XML structure in XSLT instead of the `array(xs:string*)` parameter, as shown in http://xsltransform.net/asnmyG:

```
  <xsl:param name="person-groups">
      <group>
          <person>anna</person>
          <person>abraham</person>
      </group>
      <group>
          <person>bertram</person>
      </group>
      <group>
          <person>charlotte</person>
      </group>
  </xsl:param>


  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:variable name="root" select="."/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each select="$person-groups/group">
              <xsl:apply-templates 
                 select="key('sent-by', person, $root) intersect $received-by-william | 
                         key('received-by', person, $root) intersect $sent-by-william">
                  <xsl:with-param name="correspondence" select="person[1]"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Of course both the XPath 3.1 array or the XSLT 2 XML structure could be build from your whitespace/dash separated string sequence if needed, as done for instance in http://xsltransform.net/asnmyG/1 with

```
  <xsl:param name="persons">anna-abraham bertram charlotte</xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="person-groups">
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($persons, '\s+')">
          <group>
              <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '-')">
                  <person>
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </person>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </group>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:param>
```

or in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifp2/8 with

```
  <xsl:param name="persons-string">anna-abraham bertram charlotte</xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="persons" as="array(xs:string*)"
     select="array:join(tokenize($persons-string, '\s+') ! [ tokenize(., '-') ])"/>
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew code could be so simple! – If only I could… I need a tiny tweak, as there is not only william but in fact a mrs. william as the sender/receiver as well. is it possible to include her here?   eg.  <xsl:variable name="sent-by-mrswilliam" select="key('sent-by', 'mrswilliam')"/> 
or at the intersect-part?

Comment: Not sure whether you want to select both, in that case you could use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="sent-by-william" select="key('sent-by', ('william', 'mrswilliam'))"/>` and `<xsl:variable name="received-by-william" select="key('received-by', ('william', 'mrswilliam'))"/>`.